# SDL: Delay until keyboard input

Tags: c++, sdl

Say we have (pseudo) code like this:

```
GetInput()
{
//insert keyboard stuff here
}

Update()
{
//insert rendering stuff here
}

void game::loop()
{
 game.Update();
 player.GetInput();
}
```

How will I go about waiting for the player to give input before updating whats on screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not switch the order (`GetInput` first), then block in `GetInput` and don't return until the user has entered something acceptable?

Comment: Yes but exactly how do I not return until the user has entered something acceptable? That's the whole question itself. Also I'd like to add that this is a "turn-based" game and it requires you to show the player the image first then ask them for their input. :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you really want to wait? Don't mean to be intrusive, but usually in games it's best to continue drawing stuff on the screen while waiting for *any* kind of input. Because players don't want to see the very same picture all the time.

Answer (score 0):

To make the game turn-based, I recommend an array of objects with methods that represent a player's abilities in the game. You can have a game loop, a nested round loop, a nested turn loop, and a boolean that exits the round and turn loops when a player wins.

With your current pseudocode, you could use a switch and integer in the Update method to equate these nested loops.

Example Tic Tac Toe AI:

```
#include "Shared.h"
#include "Board.h"

#ifndef AI_H_
#define AI_H_

class AI{
    public:
    AI();
    enum difficulty{Easy, Medium, Hard};
    void setAlgorithm(difficulty h);
    void applyAlgorithm(Board* b, int columns, int rows);
    private:
    Board::spot type;
        difficulty harder;
    void easy(Board* b, int columns, int rows);
    void medium(Board* b, int columns, int rows);
    void hard(Board* b, int columns, int rows);
};

#endif /*AI_H_*/
```

SDL_WaitEvent() is ridiculously more efficient than SDL_PollEvent(), if you don't want to hog the CPU.

```
while(!quit){
    if(SDL_WaitEvent(&event)){
        if(event.type == SDL_QUIT){
            quit = true;
        }else if(event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN){
            if(!menu.isClicked()){
                if(menu.handleEvent(&event)){
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```